# Intuition behind initializing both the pointers at the beginning versus one at the beginning and other at the ending

Tags: c++, algorithm, initialization, sliding-window

I solved a problem few days ago:

> Given an unsorted array `A` containing `N` integers and an integer `B`, find if there exists a pair of elements in the array whose difference is `B`.  Return `true` if any such pair exists else return `false`.  For `[2, 3, 5, 10, 50, 80]; B=40;`, it should return `true`.

as:

```cpp
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, int B) {
    if(A.size()==1) return false;
    int i=0, j=0;     //note: both initialized at the beginning

    sort(begin(A), end(A));
    while(i< A.size() && j<A.size()) {
        if(A[j]-A[i]==B && i!=j) return true;
        if(A[j]-A[i]<B) j++;
        else i++;
    }

    return false;
}
```

While solving this problem the **mistake I had committed earlier** was initializing `i=0` and `j=A.size()-1`. Due to this, decrementing `j` and incrementing `i` *both* decreased the differences and so valid differences were missed.  On initializing both at the beginning as above, I was able to solve the problem.

Now I am solving a follow-up [3sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/) problem:

> Given an integer array `nums`, return all the triplets `[nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]]` such that `i != j`, `i != k`, and `j != k`, and `nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0`.  Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.  If `nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]`, output should be: `[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]` (any order works).

A [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/7438/C%2B%2B-two-pointes-solution-(easy-way-to-handle-duplicaiton).) to this problem is given as:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) {
        if ((i>0) && (nums[i]==nums[i-1]))
            continue;
        int l = i+1, r = nums.size()-1;   //note: unlike `l`, `r` points to the end
        while (l<r) {
            int s = nums[i]+nums[l]+nums[r];
            if (s>0) r--;
            else if (s<0) l++;
            else {
                res.push_back(vector<int> {nums[i], nums[l], nums[r]});
                while (nums[l]==nums[l+1]) l++;
                while (nums[r]==nums[r-1]) r--;
                l++; r--;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

The logic is pretty straightforward: each of `nums[i]`s (from the outer loop) is the 'target' that we search for, in the inner while loop using a two pointer approach like in the first code at the top.

What I don't follow is the logic behind initializing `r=nums.size()-1` and working backwards - how are valid differences (in this case, the 'sum's actually) not being missed?

**Edit1**: Both problems contain negative and positive numbers, as well as zeroes.

**Edit2**: I understand how both snippets work.  My question *specifically* is the reasoning behind `r=nums.size()-1` in code# 2: as we see in code #1 above it, starting `r` from the end misses some valid pairs (http://cpp.sh/36y27 - the valid pair (10,50) is *missed*); so why do we not miss valid pair(s) in the second code?

Comment: If you reduce the three sum problem to the two sum problem, your question boils down to "why is searching for a pair (i, j) in a sorted array A s.t A[i] - A[j] == target different from A[i] + A[j] == target". Because the two problems are different, it's pretty obvious that they'd require a (slightly) different approach, which one could likely figure out after some experimenting/thinking.

Comment: @wLui155, well you can write "A[i] + A[j] == target" as  "A[i] - (-A[j]) == target" and then the 2 problems would become the same, right?

Comment: Well yes, `A[i] + A[j] == A[i] - (-A[j])`, but in most cases `A[i] - (-A[j]) =/= A[i] - A[j]`... anyhow in the first problem, you've already understood why you can't start at `r = nums.size() - 1`; because "decrementing `j` and incrementing `i` both decreased the difference." On the other hand, if you start with `i` and `j` at the same position, you're finding the (closest) difference to the target by essentially binary searching the **difference matrix** B, defined by B[i][j] = A[i] - A[j], which is sorted in *descending* order by row and *ascending* order by column (since A is sorted).

Comment: @ggorlen, oh, yes, I see what you mean.  Could you please elaborate what those distinct invariants are?

Comment: @ggorlen when was the sum 6?

Comment: Minor: `cout << ", isdst after: " tmstr.tm_isdst << endl;` --> `int i, j`  are each better described an _index_. Given `i< A.size()`, better to use `size_t i`.

Comment: @Someone I had some mistakes in my comments so I removed them and edited my answer, which I'm happy with now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reformulating the problem

The difference between the two algorithms boils down to addition and subtraction, not 3 vs 2 sums.

Your 3-sum variant asks for the sum of 3 numbers matching a target. When you fix one number in the outer loop, the inner loop reduces to a 2-sum that's *actually a 2-**sum*** (i.e. addition). The "2-sum" variant in your top code is really a 2-**difference** (i.e. subtraction).

You're comparing 2-sum (`A[i] + A[j] == B` s.t. `i != j`) to a 2-difference (`A[i] - A[j] == B` s.t. `i != j`). I'll use those terms going forward, and forget about the outer loop in 3-sum as a red herring.

---

### 2-sum

#### Why `L = 0, R = length - 1` works for 2-sum

For 2-sum, you probably already see the intuition of starting at the ends and working towards the middle, but it's worth making the logic explicit.

At any iteration in the loop, if the sum of `A[L] + A[R] > B`, then we have no choice but to decrement the right pointer to a lower index. Incrementing the left pointer is guaranteed to increase our sum or leave it the same and we'll get further and further away from the target, potentially closing off the potential to find the solution pair, which may well still include `A[L]`.

On the other hand, if `A[L] + A[R] < B`, then you must increase your sum by moving the left pointer forward to a larger number. There's a chance `A[R]` is still part of that sum -- we can't guarantee it's not a part of the sum until `A[L] + A[R] > B`.

The key takeaway is that there is **no decision to be made** at each step: either the answer was found or one of the two numbers at either index can be definitively eliminated from further consideration.

#### Why `L = 0, R = 0` doesn't work for 2-sum

This explains why starting both numbers at 0 won't help for 2-sum. What rule would you use to increment the pointers to find a solution? There's no way to know which pointer needs to move forward and which should wait. Both moves increase the sum at best and neither move decreases the sum (the start is the minimum sum, `A[0] + A[0]`). Moving the wrong one could prohibit finding the solution later on, and there's no way to definitively eliminate either number.

You're back to keeping left at 0 and moving the right pointer forward to the first element that causes `A[R] + A[L] > B`, then running the tried-and-true original two-pointer logic. You might as well just start `R` at `length - 1`.

---

### 2-difference

#### Why `L = 0, R = length - 1` doesn't work for 2-difference

Now that we understand how 2-sum works, let's look at 2-difference. Why is it that the same approach starting from both ends and working towards the middle won't work?

The reason is that when you're subtacting two numbers, you lose the all-important guarantee from 2-sum that moving the left pointer forward will always increase the sum and that moving the right pointer backwards will always decrease it.

In subtraction between two numbers in a sorted array, `A[R] - A[L]` s.t. `R > L`, regardless of whether you move `L` forward or `R` backwards, the sum will decrease, even in an array of only positive numbers. This means that at a given index, there's no way to know which pointer needs to move to find the correct pair later on, breaking the algorithm for the same reason as 2-sum with both pointers starting at 0.

#### Why `L = 0, R = 0` works for 2-difference

Finally, why does starting both pointers at 0 work on 2-difference? The reason is that you're back to the 2-sum guarantee that moving one pointer increases the difference while the other decreases the difference. Specifically, if `A[R] - A[L] < B`, then `L++` is guaranteed to decrease the difference, while `R++` is guaranteed to increase it.

We're back in business: there is no choice or magical oracle necessary to decide which index to move. We can systematically eliminate values that are either too large or too small and hone in on the target. The logic works for the same reasons `L = 0, R = length - 1` works on 2-sum.

---

<sub>As an aside, the first solution is suboptimal O(n log(n)) instead of O(n) with two passes and O(n) space. You can use an unordered map to keep track of the items seen so far, then perform a lookup for every item in the array: if `B - A[i]` for some `i` is in the map, you found your pair.</sub>

Comment: I do not quite agree: [here's](http://cpp.sh/36y27) the first code I setup, with `j=nums.size()-1`.  It fails on the test case: `[2, 3, 5, 10, 50, 80]; B=40`.  Another example is: `[-533, -666, -500, 169, 724, 478, 358, -38, -536, 705, -855, 281, -173, 961, -509, -5, 942, -173, 436, -609, -396, 902, -847, -708, -618, 421, -284, 718, 895, 447, 726, -229, 538, 869, 912, 667, -701, 35, 894, -297, 811, 322]; B=369`.  Could you please let me know why it fails then?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll look into it deeper and work through some examples; this was admittedly a cursory analysis on my part, but here's the thing: the 3sum problem's inner loop is basically identical to the 2sum done with sort() and two pointers as you did, so I don't see what would account for a discrepancy -- the fact that 3sum wants you to return all solutions while 2sum only needs true/false shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I did the first problem by setting `r=nums.size()-1`, but got a WA on the above test cases.  On looking further, I realized my mistake (as noted above below code 1).  Thank you for helping me out.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: OK, I didn't really stop and read the problems. The first problem is different because of subtraction whereas the second one uses the sum of the 3 numbers. For the second version, the invariant is different, because you know that you can shrink the search space, whereas in the first version, the subtraction means you don't have such a guarantee. I'll update or delete my answer soon.

Comment: But how does whether it is an addition or subtraction make a difference?

Comment: When you say, "... breaking the 2-sum algorithm for the same reason ...", you actually mean, "... breaking the 2-**difference** algorithm for the same reason ...", right?

Comment: I'm not sure what I meant, but I updated it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for sticking around and helping me out!  It clarifies my problem.  I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: No problem -- really interesting question that took a bit of time to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Conside this:

```
A = {2, 3, 5, 10, 50, 80}
B = 40

i = 0, j = 5;
```

When you have something like

```
while(i<j) {
    if(A[j]-A[i]==B && i!=j) return true;
    if(A[j]-A[i]>B) j--;
    else i++;
}
```

consider the case when `if(A[j]-A[i]==B && i!=j)` is *not true*. Your code makes an incorrect assumption that if the difference of the two endpoints is `> B` then one should decrement `j`. Given a sorted array, you don't know whether you decrementing `j` and then taking the difference would give you the target difference, or incrementing `i` and then taking the difference would give you the target number since it can go both ways. In your example, when `A[5] - A[0] != 10` you could've gone both ways, `A[4] - A[0]` (which is what you do) ***or*** `A[5] - A[1]`. Both would *still* give you a difference greater than the target difference. In short, the presumption in your algorithm is incorrect and hence isn't the right way to go about.

In the second approach, that's not the case. When the triplet `nums[i]+nums[l]+nums[r]` isn't found, you know that the array is sorted and if the sum was more than 0, it has to mean that the `num[r]` needs to be decremented since incrementing `l` would only further increase the sum further since `num[l + 1]` > `num[l]`.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question.  I fully understand how it works.  My question specifically is the reasoning behind `r=nums.size()-1` in code# 2: as we see in code #1 above it, starting from the end misses some valid pairs (http://cpp.sh/36y27); so why do we not miss valid pair(s) in the second code?

Comment: @Someone See if the updated answer addresses your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your question boils down to the following:

For a sorted array in ascending order `A`, why is it that we perform a different two-pointer search for `t` for the problem `A[i] + A[j] == t` versus `A[i] - A[j] == t`, where `j > i`?

It's more intuitive why for the first problem, we can fix `i` and `j` to be at opposite ends and decrease the `j` or increase `i`, so I'll focus on the second problem.

With array problems it's sometimes easiest to draw out the solution space, then come up with the algorithm from there. First, let's draw out the solution space `B`, where `B[i][j] = -(A[i] - A[j])` (defined only for j > i):

```
B, for A of length N
    i   ---------------------------->
j   B[0][0]     B[0][1]     ... B[0][N - 1]
|   B[1][0]     B[1][1]     ... B[1][N - 1]
|   .           .         .
|   .           .           .
|   .           .             .
v   B[N - 1][0] B[N - 1][1] ... B[N - 1][N - 1]
---
In terms of A:
X           -(A[0] - A[1])  -(A[0] - A[2])  ...  -(A[0] - A[N - 2]) -(A[0] - A[N - 1])
X           X               -(A[1] - A[2])  ...  -(A[1] - A[N - 2]) -(A[1] - A[N - 1])
.           .               .               .                       .
.           .               .                 .                     .
.           .               .                   .                   .
X           X               X               ...  X                  -(A[N - 2] - A[N - 1])
X           X               X               ...  X                  X
```

Notice that `B[i][j] = A[j] - A[i]`, so the rows of B are in *ascending* order and the columns of B are in *descending* order. Let's compute `B` for `A = [2, 3, 5, 10, 50, 80]`.

```
B = [
   i------------------------>
j  X    1    3    8    48    78
|  X    X    2    7    47    77
|  X    X    X    5    45    75
|  X    X    X    X    40    70
|  X    X    X    X    X     30
v  X    X    X    X    X     X
]
```

Now the equivalent problem is searching for `t = 40` in B. Note that if we start with `i = 0` and `j = N = 5` there's no good/guaranteed way to reach `40`. However, if we start in a position where we can always increment/decrement our current element in `B` in small steps, we can guarantee that we'll get as close to `t` as possible.

In this case, the small steps we take involve traversing either right/downwards in the matrix, starting from the top left (could equivalently traverse left/upwards from the bottom right), which corresponds to *incrementing* both `i` and `j` in the original question in A.